# Why aren't the attributes set on this self-closing haml_tag?

Tags: haml

I'm capturing haml output using the helper method `haml_tag`. However the particular element that I want to capture is a `<meta/>` tag and so I'm trying to figure out how to get a self-closing tag and also include attributes.

#### This works (almost)

```
haml_tag 'meta', '', name: :description, content: 'this is the description'
```

outputs:

```
<meta content='this is the description' name='description'></meta>
```

However I would like it to output:

```
<meta content='this is the description' name='description' />
```

#### This self-closes but doesn't print attributes...

If you pass a flag of `:/` then it should be possible to self-close the tag however in that instance the attributes don't get printed out:

```
haml_tag 'meta', nil, :/, name: :description, content: 'this is the description'
```

outputs:

```
<meta />
```

#### How can I get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the second argument if you want an empty tag:

```ruby
haml_tag 'meta', name: :description, content: 'this is the description'
```

produces:

```html
<meta content='this is the description' name='description' />
```

Note that since `meta` is one of the default empty elements you don’t need the `:/` argument, although you can add it if you want to be explicit:

```ruby
haml_tag 'meta', :/, name: :description, content: 'this is the description'
```

produces the same output as above.

There is a bug here in Haml 4.0.5, as `haml_tag` isn’t respecting the `format` option. In HTML format the output should really be:

```html
<meta content='this is the description' name='description'>
```

[This is fixed in 4.1.0.beta.1](https://github.com/haml/haml/commit/1a588cff4b2dd9375515d807dd2dc1bc996ff049).